# What are the other defines relating to #define KB_UP 72 for c++? What are all of them?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard-events

So I'm working to learn about how to get DIRECT keyboard input with c++. Right now i know how to use the getch() function and functions of that nature but I don't know how to define all the different keyboard inputs. These are the kind of ones I'm looking for.

#define KB_UP 72

#define KB_DOWN 80

#define KB_LEFT 75

#define KB_RIGHT 77

#define KB_ESCAPE 27

#define KB_ENTER 28

So ultimately what are the others, are there others? I'm working with c++ on code::blocks on windows.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the windows API doc for the winapi function  `GetAsyncKeyState()` which has a link to a page listing the virtual key codes returned by this function.  The list includes the codes you mention in your q, but they are prefixed with VK_ rather than KB_.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That information is likely to be useless if they're truly using `getch`. You need to switch from a console application to a full Windows application.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that this doesn't directly answer your question, but I've grown quite fond of this tutorial for keyboard input.

http://www.gamedev.net/blog/355/entry-2250186-designing-a-robust-input-handling-system-for-games/

You should take a look.

Answer (score 0):

> This code will help to find KB_code value of every keyboard key

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int KB_code=0;
    while(1)
    {

     if (kbhit())
      {
            KB_code = getch();
            cout<<"KB_code = "<<KB_code<<"\n";
}
    }
return(0);
}
```